Как добавить в список того кто нажал кнопку discord.py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 

client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("."), intents=discord.Intents.all())
game = None
def cs():
    game = 'cs2'
    return game
class Select(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label="cs2",emoji="",description="This is option 1!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="dota2",emoji="✨",description="This is option 2!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="valorant",emoji="",description="This is option 3!"),
            discord.SelectOption(label="своя игра",emoji="",description="This is option 3!")
            ]
        super().__init__(placeholder="Select an option",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options)
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        if self.values[0] == "cs2":
            gadde = 'Counter-Strike 2'
        elif self.values[0] == "dota2":
            gadde = 'Dota 2'
        elif self.values[0] == "valorant":
            gadde = 'Valorant'
        #start
        class Select(discord.ui.Select):
            def __init__(self):
                options=[
                    discord.SelectOption(label="1x1",emoji="",description="This is option 1!"),
                    discord.SelectOption(label="2x2",emoji="✨",description="This is option 2!"),
                    discord.SelectOption(label="5x5",emoji="",description="This is option 3!")
                    ]
                super().__init__(placeholder="Select an option",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options)
            async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
                if self.values[0] == "1x1":
                    format = '1x1'
                elif self.values[0] == "2x2":
                    format = '2x2'
                elif self.values[0] == "5x5":
                    format = '5x5'
                #start
                class Select(discord.ui.Select):
                    def __init__(self):
                        options=[
                            discord.SelectOption(label="CapitansMod",emoji="",description="This is option 1!"),
                            discord.SelectOption(label="Random",emoji="✨",description="This is option 2!")
                            ]
                        super().__init__(placeholder="Select an option",max_values=1,min_values=1,options=options)
                    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

                        if self.values[0] == "CapitansMod":
                            pik = 'CapitansMod'
                        elif self.values[0] == "Random":
                            pik = 'Random'
                        #start
                        class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
                            def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
                                super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
                            @discord.ui.button(label="Подтвердить",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green) # or .primary
                            async def green_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
                                channel = client.get_channel(1255609180153188453)
                                members = int(format[0])
                                members1 = members * 2
                                members2 = str(members1)
                                list = []
                                #start
                                
                                class Buttons(discord.ui.View):
                                    def __init__(self, *, timeout=180):
                                        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
                                    @discord.ui.button(label="Записаться",style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple) # or .primary
                                    async def blurple_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
                                        #list.append()
                                        user_id = interaction.user.id
                                        print(user_id)
                                        
                                #end
                                view=Buttons()
                                embed2 = discord.Embed(title='**Новый клоуз **|** '+gadde+' '+pik+'**',description="*Игра:* **"+gadde+"**\n*Формат:* **"+format+"**\n*Пик:* **"+pik+"**\n*Награда: * **250$**\n*Для участия нажмите кнопку ниже*\n*Клоуз начнется когда наберется *"+" **"+members2+"** "+"*участников*", color=discord.Colour.from_rgb(43, 45, 49))
                                await channel.send(embed=embed2, view=view)
                            @discord.ui.button(label="Удалить",style=discord.ButtonStyle.red) # or .secondary/.grey
                            async def red_button(self,button:discord.ui.Button,interaction:discord.Interaction):
                                await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)
                        #end
                        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"*Игра:* **"+gadde+"**\n*Формат:* **"+format+"**\n*Пик:* **"+pik+"**", view=Buttons())
                class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
                    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
                        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
                        self.add_item(Select())
                #end
                await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"*Игра:* **"+gadde+"**\n*Формат:* **"+format+"**\n*Выберите формат пика ниже*", view=SelectView())

        class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
            def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
                super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
                self.add_item(Select())
        #end
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content='*Игра:* **'+gadde+'**\n*Выберите формат ниже*', view=SelectView())
        

class SelectView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, *, timeout = 180):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.add_item(Select())

@client.command()
async def menu(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Menus!",view=SelectView())
    

client.run('

Вот мой код. Как можно сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки Записаться бот добавлял того кто нажал кнопку в список в сообщении?
